# WSUS - Machines fighting in Console

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, wsus, windows-update

Something very strange - I have two totally independent VM's (a 2008R2 box running Sharepoint and a 2008R2 DC running WSUS). Both are configured to use WSUS for patching.

However they are  both fighting over the same entry in WSUS! For example one will check in - then if I go and run a `wuauclt /reportnow` for example that will check in but replace the entry for the other server in WSUS! (and vice versa!)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The machines have the same SUSClientID, which is separate from the machine's SID.

Delete `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\SusClientId`, then restart the Windows Update service.

Answer (score 2):

The machines probably have the same SID.  You'll need to change the SID of one of them.